# why does my variable seem to be updating?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, object, children

I'm currently learning JavaScript and as far as I know have not learned anything that could explain the following:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div>One</div>
    <div>Two</div>
</div>
<script>
    function test(node) {
        var divs = node.children;
        console.log(divs);
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        node.appendChild(div);
        console.log(divs);
    }
    test(document.querySelector("#parent"));
</script>
```

I want the variable `divs` to be an object containing the children divs of `node` that exist when that line of code is run. Which it is, however it seems to update when a child is added to the parent node. What explains this behaviour; am I creating a reference to the element, and if so how do I achieve what I want to?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection, that's what `.children` gives you.

Comment: Thanks for that deceze

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, every object is passed by a reference instead of value. The .children property of a node is an object (HTMLCollection object to be specific). What that means is that 'divs' variable will not contain the children at the time it is run, it will refer to the children property. When children change and new nodes are added, accessing the divs variable will return the current state of children, so it will contain the new child as well. If you just want to just copy the reference to initial children, you can create another variable.

```
function test(node) {
    var children = node.children;
    var divs = [];

    // copy every child to the divs array
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        divs.push(children[i]);
    }

    var div = document.createElement("div");
    node.appendChild(div);

    // since divs is just an array copy of the initial children,
    // when children change, the divs still only contains the initial nodes
    console.log(divs);

    // however, as we said before, children will still be a reference to
    // current node's children, so 
    console.log(children); // outputs 3 divs
}
test(document.querySelector("#parent"));
```

Answer (score 0):

`divs` holds a reference to the `children` property of the selected node. For this reason, if you change this `children` property, the content of `divs` also changes.

If you want to keep `divs` stable, [create a shallow copy of the array-like object `children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Array-like_objects):

```
function test(node) {
    var divs = Array.prototype.slice.call(node.children);
    console.log(divs);

    var div = document.createElement("div");
    node.appendChild(div);
    console.log(divs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new array

```
var divs = new Array(node.children.length);
for(var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++){
    divs[i] = node.children[i]
}
console.log(divs);
var div = document.createElement("div");
node.appendChild(div);
console.log(divs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use querySelectorAll, it returns a static list not live. For more details you can check this link. 
https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#queryselectorall

```
<div id="parent">
    <div>One</div>
    <div>Two</div>
</div>
<script>
    function test(node) {
        var divs = document.querySelectorAll('#'+node.id +' div');
        console.log(divs);
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        node.appendChild(div);
        console.log(divs);
    }
    test(document.querySelector("#parent",'#parent div'));
</script>
```